# Data entry table, looking to add "New cell" button to generate a new row per each time clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">

            <h1 align="center">Controls Page</h1>
            </br>
            <main>
              <section id="with-container-example">
                <!-- table -->
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="table-responsive">

                      <!-- Table Titles -->
                      <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                          <tr class="alert-info">
                            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="alert('All information saved!')">Save All</button><br></br> -->
                            <input type="button" class="btn" value="Save" style="float: right;" onclick="alert('All information saved!')"><br></br>
                            <th>TEXT:</th>
                            <th>~</th>
                            <th>~</th>
                            <th>DROPDOWN</th>
                            <th>DROPDOWN</th>
                            <th>TEXT:</th>
                            <th>TEXT:</th>
                            <th>TEXT:</th>
                            <th> ADD CELL(+)
                              </>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <!-- Tables -->
                        <tbody id="myTable">
                          <tr>
                            <td>A65.1</td>
                            <td>Table Cell</td>
                            <td>Control <br> Conflictin duties and area of responsibilities .......</td>
                            <td align="center">
                              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="selectpicker">
                                                        <option>-</option>
                                                        <option>Yes</option>
                                                        <option>No</option>
                                                    </select>
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="selectpicker">
                                                        <option>-</option>
                                                        <option>Yes</option>
                                                        <option>No</option>
                                                        <option>Partially</option>
                                                    </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>Table cell</td>
                            <td>Table cell</td>
                            <td>Table cell</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>

                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>Table cell</td>
                            <td>Control <br><textarea rows="3" cols="60">Conflictin duties and area of responsibilities .......
                                                    </textarea></td>
                            <td align="center">
                              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="selectpicker">
                                                        <option>-</option>
                                                        <option>Yes</option>
                                                        <option>No</option>
                                                    </select>
                              <td align="center">
                                <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="selectpicker">
                                                        <option>-</option>
                                                        <option>Yes</option>
                                                        <option>No</option>
                                                        <option>Partially</option>
                                                    </select>
                              </td>
                              <td>Table cell</td>
                              <td>Table cell</td>
                              <td>Table cell</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>

                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>Table cell</td>
                            <td>Table cell</td>
                            <td align="center">
                              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="selectpicker">
                                                        <option>-</option>
                                                        <option>Yes</option>
                                                        <option>No</option>
                                                    </select>
                              <td align="center">
                                <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="selectpicker">
                                                        <option>-</option>
                                                        <option>Yes</option>
                                                        <option>No</option>
                                                        <option>Partially</option>
                                                    </select>
                              </td>
                              <td>Table cell</td>
                              <td>Table cell</td>
                              <td>Table cell</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/KeithDaly/pen/XaBveE)

The full open code I can give will be in the code pen link.

I designed this project with the intent to add text boxes where the "text fields" are and then where the "new cell" button is placed, I would like that to build another column beneath. If possible for assistance in text box placements or additions to jazz-it-up, open ear to all suggestions!

Thanks

Comment: fix indentation, readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have literally just done this. One way of doing it is to use jQuery to `append` a new row once a certain element has been clicked. Please see code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    jQuery(".addRow").on('click', function(){
        i++; 
        jQuery('tbody').append('<tr><td><input type="file" name="'+i+'" id="attachment"></td></tr>');
    });
});
```

Please note, you will need to put a `Class` or `ID` on the element which will be clicked to add the new row.

Comment: Thanks Lewis, how would I formulate inside the brackets that you have .append('......................') });

Your one is to add a file, I want to add a line with multiple text boxes and drop downs.
Thanks!

Comment: Will the text-boxes have values in them? or will they be entered by the user?

Comment: Entered by the user.
So TextBox, TextBox, TextBox, DropDown, DropDown, TextBox, TextBox, TextBox
will be the layout, if possible

Comment: replace my html i.e `<tr><td><input type="file" name="'+i+'" id="attachment"></td></tr>` With yours and it will work. Whatever html you punt into that append, will be appended to the specified element.

Comment: Brilliant, I have it working! Then to make a remove button, 
would it be similar. . Like jQuery('tbody').remove('...');
?

Comment: Correct, you would just do:  jQuery('element').remove();

Comment: I have the (+) button working, with (-) remove button It deletes all cells, not just one line per time. Is it possible to loop this too

Comment: Okay so what you need to do is: Each row needs to have its own id which increment by one each time. Example, Row 1 has id of 1, Row 2 has id of 2 and so on.

Once you have done this, you will need the button to to run the following jQuery code: `jQuery('#id.elementClass').remove();`